# Greedy Best First Search Algorithm, how to compute the length of its traverse?

Tags: algorithm, search, greedy

I have this problem that I am working on that has to do with the greedy best first search algorithm. However I am bit stuck on computing the length of the traverse when it comes to points (x, y). For example lets say I have these points:
(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2), (1, 3). So what I did is draw out a diagram on the x, y plane:
[image: Diagram]

Now knowing the GBF algorithm, it goes to check the closet node and so in this case the transverse would look like so: (0, 1)->(0, 2)->(1, 2)->(1, 3). So now in order to compute the length of the points connections done by the GBF, do I need to basically add up the path, which in this case would be three? Any clarifications would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first part is to find the best way to store the graph using appropriate data structure.

Say the graph looks like this now.

```
         (1,3)P4
           |
P2(0,2)--(1,2)P3
  |
(0,1)P1
  |
(0,0)P0
```

One way to represent this graph would using [Adjacency List](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list). Like this

```
P0 => P1
P1 => P2
P2 => P3
P3 => P4
```

Now using [Breath first Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) the distance between two points can be calculated in linear time. The distance between two nodes(points) with the path length being the number edges.

Explanation for BFS can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26551061/3575018)

Comment: Thank you, it made more sense now. :)